# How to format days and time like MWF 2:30-3:30 pm using Carbon in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, php-carbon

I have this project about enrollment system and would like to format in an abbreviated form including the time of the class. For example the schedule is 2:30-4:00 on monday, wednesday and friday. How can I format it to be like mwf 2:30-4:00 pm. I already read the Carbon documentation at http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ but I cannot find the format I wanted. Any help are much appreciated.

Comment: Did you read this line
echo Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H', '1975-05-21 22')->toDateTimeString(); // 1975-05-21 22:00:00

Comment: @Ivan yeah tried that.

Answer (score 1):

Carbon cannot display a date/time range like it appears you are requesting.
You would have to either work with an end time or a duration.

Assuming you are using a start time and duration:

```
$startTime = '16:00'; // stored in 24hr time
$duration = 90; // minutes
$carbonStartTime = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i', $startTime);
$formattedTime = 'MWF ' . $carbonStartTime->format('g:i') . ' - ' . $carbonStartTime->addMinutes($duration)->format('g:i a');
echo $formattedTime; // MWF 4:00 - 5:30 pm
```

[PHP Date format reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) is always handy.